# For Kafka,what IP values need to be setup in listeners & advertised.listeners value?

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-hdinsight

I have created an multi-node Azure Databricks cluster inside a VNET & I have created a multi-node Kafka HDInsight cluster inside different VNET. I have peered this 2 VNETs. After peering, my 2 machines are able to ping each other.

I am trying to dump messages to Kafka topic from Databricks cluster using Spark Structured Streaming & I am getting socket timeout error.

Upon research, I found that in Kafka we need to setup `listeners` & `advertised.listeners` in `server.properties` file.

In my scenario, what should I put the values for `listeners` & `advertised.listeners`?  Would be very helpful if anyone can suggest me what all changes I need to make in `server.properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a listener for the host/IP on which your client machine (where Spark is running) can connect to your broker.

See https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: So for "advertised.listeners", do I need to add the Databricks cluster IP? Also, do I need to change "listeners" value? I don't know what port should I add for Databricks cluster

Comment: Your HDInsight cluster should provide you with a Kafka broker — this is the port which you specify. Your `advertised.listeners` is going to be the endpoint on the HDInsight side that your databricks cluster can resolve.

Comment: I do have HDInsight cluster & I do know the Kafka broker IPs...so  is it that my advertised.listeners should be all Kafka broker IPs:9092 ??